# Query for a non existing key in a big scale mongoDB database

Tags: mongodb, database, nosql

I'm testing a little bit with mongoDB. I've created a database with a high amount of data (approx 5 million documents). When I start a query for a non existing key, it will take a lot of time. I've tried to stop the query but db.currentOp() doesn't show a operation so I don't know how to stop the query.

Cheers
Sven

Comment: Have you created an index? Also, if you are working from a cold start Mongo needs to load data.from disk into RAM which will take some time (ESP. If you're running a table scan due to a non indexed query. )

Comment: Hi Sven - I agree with Brendan, sounds like you might be querying against a field that's not indexed, so it's scanning all 5M documents.  What happens if you run find() against an `_id` value, does it still take ages? Can you post some information about your data model and query?

Comment: Hey Thynks for the fast answer. The question is about keys that are not indexed or existing. We're starting to create a data model so we don't have an exact idea - but while I was testing some queries the "endless" search occurs - I just wanted to know if there is a possibility to stop such queries which are made accidently. I hope it is now easier to understand. Cheers Sven

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try `$maxScan` operator to limit items scanned:

```
db.foo.find()._addSpecial( "$maxScan" , 50 )
```

http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Advanced+Queries#AdvancedQueries-Specialoperators